# Where is my Android Home folder?

Tags: android, macos, scala

I have Android Studio installed and can run android applications **well**. However, when I'm trying to compile an android app in scala using `sbt` and because of the way it's configured, it throws the following error:

```
[error] Android SDK not found. You might need to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT or ANDROID_HOME
```

How do I find out where my Android Home folder is to be able to set the `PATH` variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` to it? I have, however, this:

```
$ ls -al .android
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  12 alex  staff   408 Aug  3 03:48 .
drwxr--r--+ 71 alex  staff  2414 Dec 25 16:12 ..
-rw-------   1 alex  staff  1704 Jul 31 00:50 adbkey
-rw-r--r--   1 alex  staff   718 Jul 31 00:50 adbkey.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 alex  staff   191 Sep  2 15:51 androidwin.cfg
drwxr-xr-x   2 alex  staff    68 Jul 22 22:57 avd
drwxr-xr-x  24 alex  staff   816 Jul 31 00:51 cache
-rw-r--r--   1 alex  staff   155 Aug  3 03:48 ddms.cfg
-rw-r--r--   1 alex  staff  1269 Jul 23 04:43 debug.keystore
drwxr-xr-x   3 alex  staff   102 Aug  3 03:48 monitor-workspace
-rw-r--r--   1 alex  staff    85 Sep  2 15:51 repositories.cfg
-rw-r--r--   1 alex  staff   975 Jul 23 04:41 sites-settings.cfg
```

in my user's directory. Is it the folder I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SDK directory should be stored in File -> Project Structure -> SDK location.

Answer (score 1):

If it is in your system, you should find it running this command:

```
locate android-ndk|less
```